# How to count number of occurences in a Fortran array

Tags: fortran

For example if I have a 1d array

```
indices=(/1, 1, 1, 2 , 2 ,10, 11 /)
```

I want to know how many times `1` occurs (the answer should be 3).

Number 2 should be 2 times, number 10 should be 1, number 11 should also be 1.

I already tried to find out if there is intrinsic function but the `count` function works differently.

Comment: The linked question asks about "non-zero", but the extension to "equal to a specific value" is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`count`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COUNT.html) intrinsic with a comparison operator, e.g.

```
integer :: indices(7)
indices = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 10, 11]
write(*,*) count(indices==1)
```

Comment: Really dont expect it can be this simple, every source that I read, count works differently. Thank you